# How do I add a file to a directory in terminal?

Tags: bash, cvs

I am trying to add files to a directory that I created, and I attempted to use

```
   cvs add filename
```

but that did not work, as I got the error message:

```
    -bash: cvs: command not found
```

How do I fix this and be able to add files to a directory?

Comment: Do you mean "directory" when you say "dictionary"?

Comment: By `cvs`, do you mean [Concurrent Versions System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System)? It seems that you have to install it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either `cvs` has not been installed or not found in the environment path variable e.g. `$PATH`. If you're sure that you have installed `cvs` successfully, try to execute the `cvs` command by using its absolute path.

Comment: to check if its in your path do, which cvs